# How to call a Servlet when I click on a Hyperlink

Tags: jsp-tags

On a JSP Page I have populated a table with some id's. I have made these ID's as hyperlink. Now i want that if I click on any id it should go to a servlet and that particular id should also be passed to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your JSP:

```
  <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/servlet-url?id=<%=id %>">...</a>
```

to create a link which invokes the servlet at `/servlet-url` and passes the ID in the request parameter `id`.